# How to set AutoCompleteTextView drop down background to transparent in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

As the subject suggests , how to set the transparent background to AutoCompleteTextView dropdown. I can apply any style to the view(TextView) that dropdown box shows but to make the drop down itself transparent I am not able to do !

Any hints or solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks , got what I was looking for , 
I can change background image of dropdown using 
setDropDownBackgroundResource(); 
and set semi-transparent png.

Answer (score 24):

set android:popupBackground to #0FFF in xml

Answer (score 13):

You have two options:

**XML Attribute:**

[`android:popupBackground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:popupBackground)

> The background to use for the popup window.
>   May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb".

**Java Attribute**

[`setDropDownBackgroundResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setDropDownBackgroundResource(int))

> Sets the background of the auto-complete drop-down list.